# Why my mesh has black faces?

Tags: mesh, topology

I can't understand why my mesh has these black faces . . . (i have just retopology my high poly)

[image]

When i render it becomes in this way

[image]

But when i export with fbx in unity the result is this one

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's the problem please?

Comment: You have to recalculate the faces. Go into edit mode select all then click the "uv" tab on the left side panel and click "recalculate". If this still doesn't fix it you need to only select the bad faces and click "flip" in the same tab

Comment: Thank you! Anyway i have resolved the problem thanks to a prevoius question ((Why are some faces in my mesh darker?)) if you wanna check its up